# Room doesn't detect @Typeconverters

Tags: android, kotlin, gson, android-room

This is my only Entity:

```
    @Entity(tableName = "sticker_packs")
    class StickerPack(
        @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
        val identifier: Int = 0,
        var name: String,
        var publisher: String,
        @TypeConverters(StickerConverter::class)
        private var stickers: List<Sticker> = emptyList())
```

This is my custom Sticker class:

```
    data class Sticker(
    val emojis: List<String>,
    var imageDir: String,
    var size: Long = 0L)
```

This is my Database class:

```
@Database(entities = [StickerPack::class], version = 1)
//I get this same error with or without my Typeconverters here
@TypeConverters(StickerConverter::class)
abstract class StickerPacksDatabase: RoomDatabase() {

    abstract val stickerPacksDao: StickerPacksDao

    companion object{
        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE: StickerPacksDatabase? = null

        fun getInstance(context: Context): StickerPacksDatabase{
            synchronized(this){
                var instance = INSTANCE
                if(instance == null){
                    instance =
                        Room.databaseBuilder(context.applicationContext, StickerPacksDatabase::class.java, "sticker_packs_database")
                            .build()
                    INSTANCE = instance
                }
                return instance
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my `typeconverter`

```
    class StickerConverter {
    @TypeConverter
    fun stickersToJson(stickers: List<Sticker>): String = Gson().toJson(stickers)
    @TypeConverter
    fun jsonToStickers(json: String): List<Sticker> = Gson().fromJson(json)

    private inline fun <reified T> Gson.fromJson(json: String): T = fromJson(json, object: TypeToken<T>() {}.type)}
```

I'm not trying to do anything fancy just converting a list into a string with Gson, yet when trying to build the project I get the following error:

> Cannot figure out how to save this field into database. You can consider adding a type converter for it.

But that's exaclty what I'm trying to do. I may have made a mistake somewhere but I can't seem to find it. I tried moving the `@TypeConverters` notation everywhere posible and the problem persists

Comment: Have you managed to solve this? I'm facing the same problem and it's driving me crazy. I've already tested every solution in stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the `@TypeConverters` annotation to the `AppDatabase` class so that Room can use the converter that you've defined for each entity and DAO in that `AppDatabase`:

```
Database(entities = arrayOf(Sticker::class), version = 1)
@TypeConverters(StickerConverter::class)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase{
}
```

Comment: I tried it but unfortunately I'm still getting the same error message. I updated the question with my Database class

Comment: You are trying to save a list of `Sticker` to database, instead you may create one-to-many relationship between `StickerPack` and `Sticker`. right?